# Consume WSDL file using .net

Tags: c#, .net, wsdl

I am trying to consume a WSDL file from a third party in .net web API but it's retrieving.
Third-party sent me a Certificate that needs to be installed on the machine that wants to send a request and I already installed it.

In SoapUI it succeeded, with these configurations:
[image]

I can't mimic the configuration in SoupUI in .net.
This is what I have done:

```
var binding = GetBinding();
        var endpointAddress = GetEndpointAddress("Endpoint URL");
        if (endpointAddress != null)
        {


            ChannelFactory<IVitalEventsChannel> factory = null;
            IVitalEventsChannel serviceProxy = null;
            try
            {
                factory = new ChannelFactory<IVitalEventsChannel>(binding, endpointAddress);

                factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "Username";
                factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "Passowrd";

                serviceProxy = factory.CreateChannel();

                gePersonalRequest gePersonalReq = new gePersonalRequest("National number");
                serviceProxy.Open();
                var remoteAddress = serviceProxy.RemoteAddress;
                var state = serviceProxy.State;

                var result = await serviceProxy.gePersonalAsync(gePersonalReq);

                factory.Close();
                ((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy).Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //await client.CloseAsync();
                factory.Close();
                ((ICommunicationObject)serviceProxy).Close();
                return BadRequest(new { error = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

Binding part looks like this:

```
  private BasicHttpsBinding GetBinding()
    {

        var httpsBinding = new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
        httpsBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;



        //var httpsBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);

        WSHttpBinding b = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
        b.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;


        httpsBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
        httpsBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;
        httpsBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
        httpsBinding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
        httpsBinding.ReaderQuotas = XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
        httpsBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        httpsBinding.AllowCookies = true;

        return httpsBinding;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to add the service via Visual Studio's Add Web Reference or Add Service Reference functionality? SvcUtil.Exe worth giving a look as well. Autogenerated client could be messy but it should give you the details for binding settings.

Comment: Yes I tried to add the service via add service reference, but I think the binding needs tuning

Comment: Add generated .config file to the question - it'll be easier to compare generated configuration against one you've created manually. I'd enable WCF Trace temporary to see the message bodies, headers, etc. Extensive guide is in MSDN here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing